# Reactivity of primary and tertiary alkyl halides

Tags: halides, reactivity, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

From [USNCO 2004, Q58](https://www.acs.org/content/dam/acsorg/education/students/highschool/olympiad/pastexams/2004-usnco-exam-part-i.pdf#page=7):

> The reaction between which pair of reactants occurs the fastest for $[\ce{OH-}] = \pu{0.010 M}$?
>
> **(A)** $\ce{CH3CH2CH2CH2Cl + OH-}$
>
> **(B)** $\ce{(CH3)3CCl + OH-}$
>
> **(C)** $\ce{CH3CH2CH2CH2Br + OH-}$
>
> **(D)** $\ce{(CH3)3CBr + OH-}$

The following is my thought process:

- This reaction occurs through one of the S<sub>N</sub>2, S<sub>N</sub>1, E1 or E2 pathways.
- All pathways prefer better leaving groups. $\ce{Br-}$ is a better leaving group than $\ce{Cl-}$, hence **(A)** and **(B)** can be eliminated.
- The nucleophile is strongly basic, so will favor E1 and E2 reactions.

However, I am unable to choose between E1 and E2, and option **(D)** or option **(C)**, respectively.

Also, if there is any error in my reasoning, could it be pointed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this question, I think, we are not talking about priority of S<sub>N</sub>2 or E2, but according to the Clayden, **(D)** would go through E2 and **(C)** would choose S<sub>N</sub>2.

But we know that reactivity of tertiary halides are much more than primary ones. So, I think **(D)** is the right choice, either.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

(D), a tertiary halide, undergoes E2 much faster than (C), the primary halide.

Comment: How do I choose between E1 and E2 mechanisms? Does the low concentration of hydroxide rule out E2?

Comment: I don't think you can rule out a mechanism entirely, there's always a certain proportion of product that comes from the other mechanism.

Comment: As far as I understand, the reactivity of tertiary halides is greater than primary halides in both E1 and E2 reactions.